# Access Value from React Hook from a function on another page

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access a value found in a functional component from a function on another page

This WhiteTimer.js functional component is running a timer

```
let interval = null;
if (timerOn) {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTime((prevTime) => prevTime - 10);
  }, 10);
} else if (!timerOn) {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [timerOn]);
```

which calls setTime and sets the hook

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(180000);
```

then on another page I have a function

```
async function updateGame(pendingPromotion, reset) {
}
```

my aim is to get the value of const time value from whitetime.js  in to the update game function

?

Comment: By another page, you mean a separate tab? And is that page of the same origin?

Comment: Yes seperate tab

Comment: Is the page of the same origin?

Answer (score 1):

If its the same origin, you could either store the value in l[ocal or session storage](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-localstorage-react-hooks/), and then retrieve it on the next page.

If you're using Gatsby or an otherwise single page application, you could move the state ["higher" up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a parent component, thereby sharing it among the children, you'd have to pass `setTime` and `time` as props to the respective children.